# search facility flawed says no files found with 'nc6' but finds lots of files with 'ivrnc6' - does not make sense

Tags: azure-devops

I think the title says it all?

Do you need to prefix and postfix the search string with % or other characters for it to find fragments of words across source files?

Although ivrnc6 was surrounded by // in the source so not actual separate word anyway?

Comment: May I know how's the status of this issue? Do you have any other question or puzzle on this? Free to comment below:-)

Answer (score 0):

> No files found with 'nc6' but finds lots of files with 'ivrnc6'

Not know what the pattern you used which make you got the result like this.

But the **wildcards** we supported in azure devops only is `*` and `?`.

Also if you want to find fragments of words across source files, you need firstly summary its regular pattern, like start as `abc`, or others.

These are all mentioned in this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/project/search/advanced-code-search-syntax?view=azure-devops#broaden-your-search-by-using--wildcards).

> Use the wildcard characters * and ? to broaden your search criteria.
>   For example:
>
> - CodeSenseHttp* finds files containing words that start with    CodeSenseHttp, such as CodeSenseHttpClient and
>     CodeSenseHttpClientTest.
> - CodeA23?R finds files containing words that start with CodeA23, have    any alphanumeric character next, and end with R. For example, 
>     CodeA234R and CodeA23QR

You could try with these 2 wildcards we supported to achieve what you want to searched.